# rmarkdown shows TRUE column

Tags: r-markdown

In an rmarkdown documents I do

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE  , comment = NA, message= FALSE, warning = TRUE)
```


```{r include=TRUE, echo=TRUE, eval=TRUE, comment=TRUE, null_prefix = TRUE, message= FALSE}
    library(reshape2)
    #### t test
    library(reshape2)
    #head(tips)
    t.test(tips$tip, alternative ='two.sided', mu = 2.5) ### reject null of mu = 2.5

```
````

and the output has "TRUE" listed as a column down next to the ouput of t.test()

How can you remove the "TRUE"?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your chunk option `comment=TRUE`. See the [chunk options help](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/):

> comment: ('##'; character) the prefix to be put before source code
>   output; default is to comment out the output by ##, which is good for
>   readers to copy R source code since output is masked in comments (set
>   comment=NA to disable this feature)

What you are doing is asking every line to begin with TRUE. Since you already set `comment = NA` in your setup chunk, there is no need to repeat it.

````
```{r include=TRUE, echo=TRUE, eval=TRUE, null_prefix = TRUE, message= FALSE}
#### t test
library(reshape2)
#head(tips)
t.test(tips$tip, alternative ='two.sided', mu = 2.5) ### reject null of mu = 2.5
```
````